# Hibernate HQL Join Query DOT node with no left-hand-side

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two model classes

**Application.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Application", catalog = "mysqldb")
@XmlRootElement
public class Application extends BaseObject implements Serializable {
    private Long appId;
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private String desc;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AppId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getAppId() {
        return this.appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(Long appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    public Long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 128, nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "Desc")
    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User",catalog="mysqldb")
@XmlRootElement
public class Client extends BaseObject implements Serializable {
    private Long userId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name="userId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    public Long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setClientId(Long clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Column(name="Name", length=128)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have not mentioned any relationship between both.

I am trying to get a list of applications with user ID and also to get the name of user.

In my **ApplicationDaoImpl** java class I have the following method.

```
@Override
public List<ApplicationObj> getAllByUser(
        Long userId) {
    String queryString = "select application.appId as appId, application.userId as userId, user.name as name, application.name as name"
            + " from com.mydb.model.Application application join com.mydb.model.User user"
            + " with application.userId = user.userId"
            + " where application.userId=?";
    Session session = getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter(0, userId);
    List list = query.list();

    return new ArrayList<ApplicationObj>();
}
```

I am trying to get the result and set in a new object. (Setting to new object is not done yet.)

When I try executing this, I get the following exception

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getLhs(DotNode.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3516)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3302)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
    at com.mypgm.dao.hibernate.ApplicationDaoImpl.getAllByUser(ApplicationDaoImpl.java:74)
```

How to solve this? Or how to do join query without mapping any relationships

Comment: Unrelated entity joins are only possible as of Hibernate 5.1. In your case you could use a cross join and let the MySQL optimizer figure out it's an inner join which is one of the easiest optimizations a DBMS does. Use a query like `select application.appId as appId, application.userId as userId, user.name as name, application.name as name from com.mydb.model.Application application, com.mydb.model.User user WHERE application.userId=? AND application.userId = user.userId`