# java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991957/hibernate-hql-join-query-dot-node-with-no-left-hand-side) related to my problem but there is  no response from anybody. I have fallen in same problem.

I am implementing RBAC (Role Based Access Control) in Spring and Hibernate. To get all permisson I am using following query

```
String query = "SELECT P.permid,  P.permname , U.loginname, U.userid, R.rolename"
                + "      FROM net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.model.Permission AS P \n"
                + "      INNER JOIN net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.model.Rolepermission AS RP ON P.permid = RP.permid\n"
                + "      INNER JOIN net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.model.Role AS R ON R.roleid=RP.roleid\n"
                + "      INNER JOIN net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.model.Userrole AS UR ON UR.roleid=R.roleid\n"
                + "      INNER JOIN net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.model.Usercredential AS U ON u.userid=UR.userid\n"
                + "       WHERE U.loginname='akash' AND RP.deleted=false AND UR.deleted= false";
```

And my Java code is like that

```
List<Object> results=getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).list();
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
type Exception report

message DOT node with no left-hand-side!

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getLhs(DotNode.java:670)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:647)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:389)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3858)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3644)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.service.impl.UsercredentialService.getPermissionsByUserLoginName(UsercredentialService.java:377)
    net.lynncom.fieldforce.persistence.service.impl.UsercredentialService.loadUserByUsernameandPassword(UsercredentialService.java:280)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.loadUserByUsernameandPassword(Unknown Source)
    net.lynncom.fieldforce.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:43)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.3 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
```

Comment: Please ignore the Run Code snippet buttons. Actually I am trying to discard this buttons.

Comment: Case matters: `AS U ON u.userid` should be `AS U ON U.userid`. But anyway, this is not HQL. Joins are made using associations between entities in HQL. You should not have the ID of another entity in any entity. You should have a ManyToOne or OneToOne association instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed this but still giving same errors. 

But this query worked for me String query = "SELECT P.permid,  P.permname , U.loginname,U.userid, R.rolename
                      FROM  Permission P ,Rolepermission RP,Role R,Userrole UR,Usercredential U
                      WHERE P.permid = RP.permid AND
                        R.roleid=RP.roleid AND
                        UR.roleid=R.roleid AND
                        U.userid=UR.userid AND
                        U.loginname='akash'";